# Optimising ruby regexp -- lots of match groups

Tags: ruby, regex, optimization, pattern-matching, lexer

I'm working on a ruby baser lexer. To improve performance, I joined up all tokens' regexps into one big regexp with match group names. The resulting regexp looks like:

```
/\A(?<__anonymous_-1038694222803470993>(?-mix:\n+))|\A(?<__anonymous_-1394418499721420065>(?-mix:\/\/[\A\n]*))|\A(?<__anonymous_3077187815313752157>(?-mix:include\s+"[\A"]+"))|\A(?<LET>(?-mix:let\s))|\A(?<IN>(?-mix:in\s))|\A(?<CLASS>(?-mix:class\s))|\A(?<DEF>(?-mix:def\s))|\A(?<DEFM>(?-mix:defm\s))|\A(?<MULTICLASS>(?-mix:multiclass\s))|\A(?<FUNCNAME>(?-mix:![a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*))|\A(?<ID>(?-mix:[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*))|\A(?<STRING>(?-mix:"[\A"]*"))|\A(?<NUMBER>(?-mix:[0-9]+))/
```

I'm matching it to my string producing a MatchData where exactly one token is parsed:

```
bigregex =~ "\n ... garbage"
puts $~.inspect
```

Which outputs

```
#<MatchData
 "\n"
 __anonymous_-1038694222803470993:"\n"
 __anonymous_-1394418499721420065:nil
 __anonymous_3077187815313752157:nil
 LET:nil
 IN:nil
 CLASS:nil
 DEF:nil
 DEFM:nil
 MULTICLASS:nil
 FUNCNAME:nil
 ID:nil
 STRING:nil
 NUMBER:nil>
```

So, the regex actually matched the "\n" part. Now, I need to figure the match group where it belongs (it's clearly visible from #inspect output that it's _*anonymous*-1038694222803470993, but I need to get it programmatically).

I could not find any option other than iterating over #names:

```
m.names.each do |n|
  if m[n]
    type = n.to_sym
    resolved_type = (n.start_with?('__anonymous_') ? nil : type)
    val = m[n]
    break
  end
end
```

which verifies that the match group did have a match.

The problem here is that it's slow (I spend about 10% of time in the loop; also 8% grabbing the `@input[@pos..-1]` to make sure that **\A** works as expected to match start of string (I do not discard input, just shift the @pos in it).

You can check the full code at [GH repo](https://github.com/farcaller/rly/blob/master/lib/rly/lex.rb#L128).

Any ideas on how to make it at least a bit faster? Is there any option to figure the "successful" match group easier?

Comment: Just FYI, [Rob Pike says "You're doing it wrong"](http://commandcenter.blogspot.com/2011/08/regular-expressions-in-lexing-and.html)

Comment: Very good point, but using RE for lexer makes it pretty trivial to develop (development time saved). I'm thinking about a more straightforward approach for lexer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the regexp methods `.captures()` and `.names()`:

```
matching_string = "\n ...garbage"   # or whatever this really is in your code
@input = matching_string.match bigregex   # bigregex = your regex
arr = @input.captures

arr.each_with_index do |value, index|     
  if not value.nil?
    the_name_you_want = @input.names[index]
  end
end
```

Or if you expect multiple successful values, you could do:

```
success_names_arr = []
success_names_arr.push(@input.names[index]) #within the above loop
```

Pretty similar to your original idea, but if you're looking for efficiency `.captures()` method should help with that.

Comment: Sure. But at that point I wouldn't know, what part of combined regexp matched (i.e. what is the original token name).

Comment: Then perhaps try using pre_match?  `a = @input.match(/your_regex/).pre_match`. If i'm understanding your code correctly, the pre_match would be exactly the name? (You may need to gsub out the colon).

Comment: On a slightly separate note, in your code you can DRY it up a little (lines 129-131) `val, type, resolved_type = nil`

Comment: Updated the question with more details on where do I get matchdata from and what I miss

Comment: Okay the added info was helpful.  I updated my answer above ^^. That should work for you

Comment: Ok, this one seems to look the best. I have `@input.captures.length > @input.names.length` though, but it's probably my bug.

Answer (score 1):

I may have misunderstood this completely but but I'm assuming that all but one token is not `nil` and that's the one your after?

If so then, depending on the flavour of regex you're using, you could use a negative lookahead to check for a non-`nil` value

```
([^\n:]+:(?!nil)[^\n\>]+)
```

This will match the whole token ie `NAME:value`.

Comment: Only one token is not nil, but I need to figure which one. The regex is a concatenation of per-token regexes to make things fast.

Comment: I'm not well up on ruby so the implementation might need tweaking but the above regex will match a string containing `:` which is not followed by `nil`. You can then split the captured string based on the colon. I have also amended the regex to take into account the closing `>`

Comment: Let me get it correct, you're suggesting to regex-match the MatchData#inspect ?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means